# How to Scan and process nested arrays?

Tags: postgresql, go

I am trying to map an array of objects that one of the properties is array. See the structs bellow and function I am trying.

```go
type CommentMock struct {
    Text string
}

type ArrticleMock struct {
    ID         string
    Title      string
    Comments   interface{}
}

func CommentDataLoader(db *sql.DB, keys dataloader.Keys) []*dataloader.Result {
    sqlStatement := "SELECT a.id, a.title, array_agg(c.text) AS comments  FROM articles a JOIN comments c ON a.id = c.article_id WHERE a.id IN (10) GROUP BY a.id"
    row, err := db.Query(sqlStatement)
    if err != nil {
        return nil
    }
        for row.Next() {
            var article ArrticleMock
            err := row.Scan(&article.ID, &article.Title, &article.Comments)
            if err != nil {
                return nil
            }
            fmt.Println(article)
            // Here I do not know how to proceed further more and map comments. See bellow the output of this print.
        }
}
```

```
// fmt.Println(article) output
&{0x40001841b0 0x105670 0x4000074320 <nil> <nil> {{0 0} 0 0 0 0} false <nil> [10 Randy Rides Alone [123 34 87 104 97 116 32 104 97 112 112 101 110 101 100 34 44 34 78 117 108 108 97 109 32 109 111 108 101 115 116 105 101 32 110 105 98 104 32 105 110 32 108 101 99 116 117 115 46 32 80 101 108 108 101 110 116 101 115 113 117 101 32 97 116 32 110 117 108 108 97 46 34 44 34 78 117 108 108 97 32 110 105 115 108 46 34 44 34 78 97 109 32 116 114 105 115 116 105 113 117 101 32 116 111 114 116 111 114 32 101 117 32 112 101 100 101 46 34 44 34 80 114 111 105 110 32 97 116 32 116 117 114 112 105 115 32 97 32 112 101 100 101 32 112 111 115 117 101 114 101 32 110 111 110 117 109 109 121 46 32 73 110 116 101 103 101 114 32 110 111 110 32 118 101 108 105 116 46 32 68 111 110 101 99 32 100 105 97 109 32 110 101 113 117 101 44 32 118 101 115 116 105 98 117 108 117 109 32 101 103 101 116 44 32 118 117 108 112 117 116 97 116 101 32 117 116 44 32 117 108 116 114 105 99 101 115 32 118 101 108 44 32 97 117 103 117 101 46 32 86 101 115 116 105 98 117 108 117 109 32 97 110 116 101 32 105 112 115 117 109 32 112 114 105 109 105 115 32 105 110 32 102 97 117 99 105 98 117 115 32 111 114 99 105 32 108 117 99 116 117 115 32 101 116 32 117 108 116 114 105 99 101 115 32 112 111 115 117 101 114 101 32 99 117 98 105 108 105 97 32 67 117 114 97 101 59 32 68 111 110 101 99 32 112 104 97 114 101 116 114 97 44 32 109 97 103 110 97 32 118 101 115 116 105 98 117 108 117 109 32 97 108 105 113 117 101 116 32 117 108 116 114 105 99 101 115 44 32 101 114 97 116 32 116 111 114 116 111 114 32 115 111 108 108 105 99 105 116 117 100 105 110 32 109 105 44 32 115 105 116 32 97 109 101 116 32 108 111 98 111 114 116 105 115 32 115 97 112 105 101 110 32 115 97 112 105 101 110 32 110 111 110 32 109 105 46 32 73 110 116 101 103 101 114 32 97 99 32 110 101 113 117 101 46 34 125]]}
```

Why am I getting this []byte or whatever this is for Comments? How to map them?

Comment: I guess the byte array is a string, what is the output if you try: `fmt.Println(string( article.Comments))`?

Comment: Use https://github.com/davecgh/go-spew to inspect and consider use sqlx to load the structure easily (ser https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx )

Comment: If you want inspect easily your structures, create a `String() string` method (pointer method to work better) and you can define it on the subsequent nested structures too. This is the **stringer** interface